# Regex for phone numbers with * in it

Tags: java, regex

I have created a regex for phone numbers as follows `\\d+ ?\\w{0,9} ?\\d+` . Now i have a problem that this only accepts numbers. Sometimes i receive the phone number as starified
so it can be 011***1334. How can i incorporate the stars portion into the above regex expression.

Comment: Basically you are solving the wrong problem - what does the regex validation give you over just allowing anything and why would you accept your 011***1334 surely if there is any loin it s to accept only numbers

Comment: Why do you allow word characters (`\w`) in between your numbers (and asterisks)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble getting your regex to work in the first place, without stars,

but anyway... you can represent the star by escaping it.

`\*`

So you should just turn all of your `\d` into `[\d\*]` or `[\\d\\*]` if you have to escape the `\` first in your java.

Some regular expression engines don't require you to escape all special characters in `[]` so I'd watch for that behavior if it doesn't work at first

Comment: Your last sentence is not correct. Characters are not automatically escaped in a character class. Inside a character class there are only 4 chars that have a special meaning (that needs escaping): `-\]` and `^` but this only at the first position inside the class. Normally it does not hurt if there are escaped characters, so no problem to use `[\\d\\*]`, but `[\\d*]` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere you use `\\d`, turn it into `[\\d\\*]`

```
[\\d\\*]+ ?\\w{0,9} ?[\\d\\*]+
```

I agree with Sam I am though; the original seems odd. If you just need numbers and asterisks, this should do (escaped Java-style):

```
[\\d\\*]{7,10}
```